# SQL Server SSIS: How do I merge a date and a time column imported from Excel into one column for OLE destination?

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have this Excel report that comes out of a poorly designed tool that insists on splitting date and time into their own columns on excel exports. I need to have date and time as one column to do `datediff` and other calculations in T-SQL for metrics.

I'm trying to build an SSIS package that will import the excel file into a SQL Server table (to avoid the manual labor of manipulating spreadsheets), but I'm having issues figuring out how to merge the two columns into one.

Here's my set up:

Excel Source

```
Date Originated: 2015-10-02 (or sometimes 10/02/2015)

Time Originated: 1:01PM (or sometimes 13:01, <-hence poorly designed)
```

Derived Column

```
Derived Column Name: N_DateOriginated

Derived Column: <add as new column> 

Expression: [Date Originated]+[Time Originated]

Data Type: Unicode string [DT_WSTR] (can not change this)

Length: 510
```

Data Conversion

```
Input Column: N_DateOriginated

Output Alias: C_DateOriginated
DataType: DT_Date
```

OLE Destination

```
Mapping: C_DateOriginated - DateOriginated
```

Errors:

[Data Conversion [2]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "N_DateOriginated" (17) to column "Copy of N_DateOriginated" (6).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

[Data Conversion [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of N_DateOriginated]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of N_DateOriginated]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (3). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[Excel Source [23]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on Excel Source returned error code 0xC02020C4. The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: What is your issue? Is the result not what you're expecting? Are you get an error?

Comment: I'm not getting a result at all actually. It's throwing errors and does not complete the import.

Comment: Try converting to string during concatenation and pass it up to SQL as string and let sql cast the string back at its interface point.     I  personally like   04-Jul-1776  14:02:15  .  double check am pm scenarios you would be surprised what happens sometimes.